# Sequelize foreign key vs SQL how to implement it

Tags: sql, orm, sequelize.js, foreign-keys

I'm new to sequelize and I have 2 tables:
User
Adress

MERISE methods:
A user can have one ore more address: 0,n.
An address is related to only one user: 1,1.

So my Foreign Key is id_user in Address table.

My question is: HOW TO DO IT in sequelize ?

My current code:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const User = sequelize.define(
      "User",
      {
        id_user: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        login: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
          allowNull: false,
          unique: true,
        },
        password: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING,
          allowNull: false,
        },
        email: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
          allowNull: false,
        },
      },
    );
  
    return User;
  };

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
 const Address = sequelize.define(
      "Address",
      {
        id_address: {
          type: DataTypes.UUID,
          defaultValue: DataTypes.UUIDV4,
          allowNull: false,
          primaryKey: true,
        },
        street: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(100),
          allowNull: true,
        },
        postCode: {
          type: DataTypes.CHAR(5),
          allowNull: false,
        },
        city: {
          type: DataTypes.STRING(32),
          allowNull: false,
        },
      },
    );
  
    return Address;
  };
```

Comment: You shuld look at Associations - https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/assocs/ In your case you need `hasMany` from `User` to Address and `belongsTo` from Address to User